# Printing defined integers in C

Tags: c, printf, parameter-passing, c-preprocessor

I have defined an integer in C as

```
#define FOO_VERSION 04042012
```

when I go to pass this to a function like so:

```
unsigned int version = FOO_VERSION;
bar(version);
```

the actual value passed is 1065994.
I verified this using GBD, printf-ing the variable version and by printf-ing the define:
'FOO_VERSION'

My question is what is causing this , I can't see any reason unless there is some sort of type conversion going on that I do not know about?

Comment: a leading 0 makes the integer seen as an octal value.  I.E. remove the leading 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literal integers starting with a leading `0` is an octal in C.

Thus `04042012` (base 8) is `1065994` in (base 10).

Comment: Note that even if the constant would *not* be converted to octal, the result as integer would still loose the leading zero. Presumably the OP wants this as a date, and so it would better be defined as a string instead.

Comment: Agreed. But I am not sure if OP wants base 10 (in that case remove the leading 0) or in print in octal (in that use`%o` in printf) or string as you stated in case of date (which is most likely by the looks of it).

Comment: would placing a leading u in front of the number (u04042012) resolve this also. And yes the date is intended to be used.

Comment: @The_Neo If you intend to use it as date, using as a string is a better option: `#define FOO_VERSION "04042012"` or `const char *FOO_VERSION="04042012";` and `%s` when printing it using printf(especially if it's intended to be a constant). For example, if `sizeof(int)` is 2 (assuming byte=8bits), then a date like `30122014` can't represented in an integer.

Answer (score 3):

`04042012` is an octal (base 8) integer constant because of the initial 0. Remove it to define a decimal (base 10) integer:

```
#define FOO_VERSION 4042012
```

Answer (score 2):

Literals starting with `0` are in base 8

```
#define FOO_VERSION_8 04042012 // base 8
#define FOO_VERSION 4042012 // base 10
```

you can print extra zeros with `printf()`

```
printf("Version %08d\n", FOO_VERSION); // prints 04042012
//               ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Integers starting with a leading 0 are octal notation in C.

04042012 is base 8. without any leading sign it is base 10.

You might also find interesting that
leading 0x is hexa decimal (Base 16).

so 0x10 would be 16 decimal.